# Как добавить способ оплаты картой в интернет-магазине на opencart?

Tags: opencart, cms, интернет-магазин

Недавно я создал интернет-магазин на opencart. (делаю это впервые) Столкнулся с таким явлением - допустим, во время оформления заказа нужно выбрать способ оплаты, чтобы был картой, и дальше должен быть номер карты, на которую нужно будет перевести деньги. Но при выборе появляется только один вариант - оплата на месте. Как только ни пробовал добавить оплату картой, ничего не получается. Буду рад, если поможете.